# hibernate error in Java Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Hello im new to programming and i try to make a car rental program using Java inside NetBeans (im new to programming also) and using a MySQL database with MySQL workbench

```html
Dec 28, 2014 3:23:11 PM     org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
Dec 28, 2014 3:23:11 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
Dec 28, 2014 3:23:11 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Dec 28, 2014 3:23:11 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Dec 28, 2014 3:23:11 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Dec 28, 2014 3:23:11 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Dec 28, 2014 3:23:11 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at ui.splash.login.LoginSection.performLogin(LoginSection.java:90)
 at ui.splash.login.LoginSection.actionPerformed(LoginSection.java:80)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class [ BranchAddress] declared in Hibernate configuration <mapping/> entry
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2279)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2227)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2207)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:213)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:46)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2160)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:201)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:46)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2075)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:183)
 at database.SessionManager.<init>(SessionManager.java:18)
 at database.SessionManager.<clinit>(SessionManager.java:12)
 ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BranchAddress
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
 at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:193)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2276)
 ... 49 more'
```

here are my hibernate.xml configurations:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <mapping class="domain.Agency"/>
    <mapping class="domain.Booking"/>
    <mapping class="domain.Branch"/>
    <mapping class="BranchAddress"/>
    <mapping class="domain.Car"/>
    <mapping class="domain.CarType"/>
    <mapping class="domain.Customer"/>
    <mapping class="domain.CustomerAddress"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BranchAddress` is BranchAddress on your classpath?

Comment: yes BranchAddress is on my classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<mapping class="BranchAddress"/>
```

Having a class in the default package is always a bad practice in Java. Such a class can't be imported in any other packages. I think you need to move this class to proper package.

Comment: Are you sure BranchAddress class is placed correctly in your project structure? You got ClassNotFoundException again?

Comment: yes, can i upload the project so someone can help me or skype with someone or team viewer?

Comment: Do you have your hibernate.cfg.xml configuration file in the root of your application's classpath?

Comment: no, how can i do that? :/ sorry for the dumb questions but im new to Java

Comment: i need to create a hbm for each class? or one for all?